# Site icon is an empty balloon in Mac browsers

Tags: bug, design

On Safari and Chrome on Mac OS X, the site icon is an empty balloon - the letters 'EC' are not visible. When disabling a CSS rule, the bug disappears:

*Normal:*

[image]

*CSS rule disabled:*

[image]

Clearing the browser cache didn't solve the problem. As a heavy Mac user, I didn't realize this bug until I checked the site with Internet Explorer on Windows ...

#### EDIT:

A few months later, the problem seems to be solved for the main site, but not for the meta site:

[image]

Comment: This is not just on Macs - Chrome and Firefox (latest versions) on Windows show the same bug